# Returning Expected Array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to put together a query that is racking my brain.

```
Users Table
===================
user_id primary key
role_id integer

Characters Table
=====================
character_id  integer
owned_by integer (0 if not owned and if owned will show user_id from users table)
```

For each role there is a specific type of query that needs to be ran.

Role_id

1. (fans) : no query is to be ran.
2. (basic users) : should be a list of any characters that are returned with the user_id associated to that character
3. (editors) : should be a list of characters that are returned with that user_id and all other basic user's characters, and not owned characters
4. (admins) should be a list of characters that are returned with that user_id and all other basic user's and editor characters, and not owned characters
5. (webmaster) should be a list of characters that are returned with that user_id and all other basic user's characters, and editor characters and owned admin owned characters and not owned characters

I thought about doing this in one query but I"m wondering if that might be a bad idea.

Comment: Will a moderator please delete this post as I decided to do a different route with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not make use of the `switch` command?

```
switch($type) {
   case 'basic users' : 
    //do something
   break;
   case 'editors' : 
    //do something
   break;
   case 'admins' : 
    //do something
   break;
   case 'webmaster' : 
    //do something
   break;
   default:
     //Don't do anything, as no query is to be run
     //aka: fans
   break;
}
```

Where `//do something`, insert the logic you require?

Comment: I did do that exact thing in my controller however I'm trying to come up with the queries.

Comment: Something like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4847/1 ?